# Configure both central and third party repositories in pom.xml

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I have maven project which downloads jars from nexus central repository.But i am using some oracle jars which are not getting downloaded from central repository because of licensing.so i have downloaded them in nexus thirdparty repository.So when jar is not getting downloaded from central, it should download it from thirdparty repository.

What configurations needs to be done in settings.xml and pom.xml?

Comment: What do you mean by " from nexus central repository"? Do you mean a corporate repository?

Comment: nexus central repository is maven central repository

Answer (score -1, accepted):

found answer in below link
https://blog.sonatype.com/2008/11/adding-a-jar-to-a-maven-repository-with-sonatype-nexus/

configured settings.xml as mentioned above